# Custom Http headers names manipulation by Spring framework

Tags: spring, rest, http, spring-mvc, http-headers

I am having Rest service exposed (using Spring framework ) where in I am trying to access custom http headers. When I am retrieving the headers in the controller class , Strange thing I observed is that spring framework is converting case of header names to camel case.

For example if I call rest service from soap UI by passing the http header name as "RAVIKUMAR" in caps , what I am seeing  in the controller class, header name is now "RaviKumar" .

I know as per http spec , header names are case-insensitive. But I want to see the logic how spring framework is playing with header names . Does anyone know which class in Spring has this logic ?

I tried to have a look and related class but could not find the place where its converting the headernames to camel case.

https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/master/spring-web/src/main/java/org/springframework/http/HttpHeaders.java

There is one place where it seems that its converting the headernames to lower case but not to camel case.

https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/master/spring-core/src/main/java/org/springframework/util/LinkedCaseInsensitiveMap.java

Any help in this regard will be highly appreciated.